# Streamsend API with C#

Tags: c#, api, streamreader

I cannot seem to get this code to work with `Streamsends API`. I have been all over the internet and have found very little info pertaining to what I am trying to do. I am trying to upload a file to their server. Can anyone look at this and maybe help me out here?

I keep getting a 500 error from Streamsends servers which they say is within the Streamsend application itself. What is funny is if I take the line near the bottom that is commented out

(`//request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";`)

and uncomment it I get a 422 error which is saying invalid data. It seems like there is something wrong with the boundary.

I am fairly new to C# and this is the first time I have worked with Streamsends API so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
m_Method = "POST"
m_Action = "uploads"
private string StreamSendResponse(string Path, string FileName)
    {
        string sReturn = String.Empty;
        string sLocation = String.Empty;

        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        byte[] boundarybytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + Environment.NewLine);

        Uri addy = new Uri(m_URI + m_Action);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(addy);
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;           

        request.Method = m_Method;

        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Merv.base64Encode(m_ID + ":" + m_Key));

        Stream rs = request.GetRequestStream();

        string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n{1}";
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

        foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
        {
            rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);
            string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]);
            byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
            rs.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);
        }

        rs.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\n Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";

        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "data", FileName);

        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
        rs.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path + FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();

        byte[] trailer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Environment.NewLine + "--" + boundary + "--" + Environment.NewLine);

        rs.Write(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
        rs.Close();

        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        //request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader srResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            sLocation = response.Headers["Location"];
            sReturn = srResponse.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        catch (WebException exc)
        {

            StreamReader srResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            sReturn = srResponse.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            sLocation = exc.Message;
        }
        if (sReturn == String.Empty)
        {
            sReturn = sLocation;
        }

        return sReturn;
    }
```

Comment: You already set the `ContentType` of the request near the top of the method, including the boundary. Uncommenting the commented like would probably overwrite the `ContentType` with a value without a boundary. Perhaps that explains the 422 response.

Comment: I understand that, thats why I feel there is something wrong with my boundary.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I thought you didn't know you already set it :) You could use Fiddler to see what data you're actually sending. It also reports HTTP protocol violations if it detects any.